# cdk virtualscroll with mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material2, angular-cdk, virtualscroll

Is there a virtual scroll implementation that works with the grid-list? I think the default implementation won't work because each row should have an element around it.

I'm using the grid-list to display profile pictures, and need an infinite scroll or preferably virtual scroll to load new ones.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: @emillime I ended up using ngx-virtual-scroller, and rolled out my own tiles, which was actually not that much work and works great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So since cdk virtualscroll doesn't support multi column, I ended up using [ngx-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller), which does support multi-columns. The mat-grid-list I also had to let go because of this, but, creating your own tiles isn't that much work when using flexbox.

Here's a snippet using multi columns, [users-online-tile] is a component that represents a user-picture with a name. The IsHandset boolean (from cdk) I use to set the height of the tile so more or less tiles are displayed depending on the screen size.

Hope this helps someone

```html
    <virtual-scroller [items]="users" (vsUpdate)="onVsUpdate($event)" (vsEnd)="fetchMore($event)"
      (vsChange)="onVsChange($event)" [scrollbarWidth]="20" [scrollbarHeight]="100" [bufferAmount]="100">
      <div [ngClass]="{ 'users-online-tile' :  (isHandset$ | async), 'users-online-tile-desktop' : !(isHandset$ | async) }" 
              *ngFor="let user of scrollItems">
        <div [users-online-tile]="user" [isHandset]="(isHandset$ | async)"></div>
        <!-- <div class="item">{{user.userName}}</div> -->
      </div>
    </virtual-scroller>
```

Comment: Hi,
How did you achieve the responsiveness like mat-grid-list? As in mat-grid-list, we can change the no of columns in one row. How did you do while using simple divs? Can you please guide me on it?

Comment: @user3768904 like I said in my answer: I use IsHandset (from cdk) to determine if the device is a handset or not. I pass that boolean to my 'users-online-tile' component. In the component I use a simple ngClass to alternate between handset height and desktop. This way, the amount of tiles displayed will be more or less.

Comment: @ElgerMensonides is this still the only way of creating a scrollable grid?

Comment: @PaxForce as far as I can tell yes unfortunately

Comment: I tried this code, but it only displays a single coloumn