# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport usage with angular/flex-layout (row and wrap)

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I would like to use virtual scrolling with flexlayout - e.g. the following code should work with virtual scrolling:

```html
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <div *ngFor="let size of fixedSizeData; let i = index" [style.height.px]="size">
      <div style="border: 1px dashed; padding: 6px;" [style.height.px]="size - 20">
        Item #{{i}} - ({{size}}px)
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I [made a little demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tikbvh) which shows the result (without `virtualscroll`) and an attempt to do the same with `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887154/17570866) is pretty much what you are asking for.